# Using a windows user to authorize in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, windows-authentication, cancancan

I am doing authentication with windows, wanted to know how to use this user's windows to authorize with the cancancan? I've already tried to get the user with `ENV ['USERNAME']` and it's not working, it set once, and it does not work any more. I tried to pass via cookie, until I got to create a cookie in asp, but I do not know how to make the rails use.

Comment: You can't get a user's *operating system* login info from your Rails' server.

Comment: It's from iis, I'm just using windows authentication.